# pandas str.extract with additional logic (lambda ?)

Tags: python, pandas

I have many types of dates in the text:

- 04/20/2009;
- 04/20/09;
- 4/20/09;
- 4/3/09
- 04-20-2009;

And many more.

I'm working on a RegEx (or several RegEx's) to extract the dates.

Lucky pandas has a very useful function called extract, for example this extracts very well most of my dates:

```
df['text'].str.extract(r'(\d{1,2})[\/-](\d{1,2})[\/-](\d{1,4})', expand=True)
```

As you can see above, I have 3 capture groups. This creates 3 columns: month, day, year.

Is it possible somehow to run a lambda on them and create a single column?

The same way you use lambdas on "replace"

```
df['text'].str.replace(r'(\w+day\b)', lambda x: x.groups()[0][:3])
```

Comment: There are libraries which will do date parsing for you.

Comment: You might want to do something to handle the year before you combine them though. E.g., if you wanted to make all years four digits.

Comment: @StephenRauch Thanks, it is just an example, the question is it possible to run somehow lambdas on the capturing groups

Comment: Does `pd.to_datetime` not do most of the work for you here?

Comment: I second @JonClements, at least with the data above, pandas date time is able to convert all the dates in correct format.

Comment: @Vaishali as I said, the dates are just an example. And I have many more date types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could avoid the problem of separate columns by tweaking your regular expression to use one capture group. Something like this would work for the date formats you've provided:

```
df.date.str.extract(r'([0-9]{1,2}[\/\.\-][0-9]{1,2}[\/\.\-][0-9]{1,4})', expand=False)
```

You could further convert the result to datetime:

```
df['my_date_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['my_date_col'])
```

To prove that `pd.to_datetime` is lenient:

```
import pandas as pd

lst = ['04/03/2009', '04/03/09', '4/03/09', '4/3/09', '04-03-2009',
       '4-3-09', '3 Apr 2009', '3rd April 2009', '3-Apr-09', '3-Apr-2009',
       '04/3/09', '04-3-09', '04-3-2009', '4-03-2009']

set(map(pd.to_datetime, lst))

# {Timestamp('2009-04-03 00:00:00')}
```

Answer (score 1):

The output of the `pandas.DatFrame.str.extract()` is a dataframe.  You can use `pandas.DataFrame.apply()` on that if needed like:

#### Code:

```
dates = df['text'].str.extract(extract_re, expand=True).apply(
    lambda row: row.str.cat(sep='/'), axis=1)
```

#### Test Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame("""
    04/20/2009;
    04/20/09;
    4/20/09;
    4/3/09
    04-20-2009;
""".split('\n')[1:-1], columns=['text'])
print(df)

extract_re = r'(\d{1,2})[\/-](\d{1,2})[\/-](\d{1,4})'
dates = df['text'].str.extract(extract_re, expand=True).apply(
    lambda row: row.str.cat(sep='/'), axis=1)
print(dates)
```

#### Results:

```
              text
0      04/20/2009;
1        04/20/09;
2         4/20/09;
3           4/3/09
4      04-20-2009;

0    04/20/2009
1      04/20/09
2       4/20/09
3        4/3/09
4    04/20/2009
dtype: object
```